# Angularjs sortable wrong order on view

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've been working around with Angularjs and sortable / draggable. Everything seems to work fine until I change the elements's position within the sortable. The order of the list is right but on the view, it's in the wrong order. This happens if I have more than 2 items in the sortable list, I also have a demo link for reference:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JDnm9OmvZl2ggXBlfbyd

Try to have 2 items and sort within the sortable, it works

Try to have **more than 2 items** and **drag from index 0 to 1**, you will see the problem

Would really appreciate if you guys can help me

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: FOUND THE SOLUTION**

Just a quick note that I've found the solution to this one by chance,
In stead of using

```
ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"
```

I removed the **"track by $index"** part and it works. Now it is something like

```
ng-repeat="item in items"
```

Hope this help, cheers

Anyway, now the solution has been clear, but I'm still not so sure about this, why removing that **track by $index** makes it work ? Can anyone clear me up with this ?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Maybe you should report it.